# Unable to login into magento admin

Tags: magento

I am not able to Open admin page and I am not even able to see any sort of errors on then page. 
"Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime
or capacity problems. Please try again later."
if i give any url of my magento site I am getting the above output. How do I resolve this? Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a file named `maintenance.flag` at the root folder of your Magento. This file is there to provide people to access a given magento when you are doing maintenance on it.
Try removing this file from your magento root folder.